# How to compute iterative functions in shiny using the reactive programming

Tags: r, recursion, iteration, shiny, reactive-programming

I want to build a shiny app that takes one slider input (say, k) and calculate vectors x and y of length 10 each, defined as follows:

```
x[1] = 1
y[1] = 2
    for ( i in 2:10 ){
        x[i] = k*x[i-1] + y[i-1]
        y[i] = x[i]/k + x[i-1] + 2*y[i-1]
                     }
```

Then I want to plot y versus x.

I am not sure how to use the "reactive" environment correctly to accomplish this task. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the code you have there inside `reactive({ ... })` and have the last expression be `list(x=x, y=y)`. And change `k` to `input$k`.

```
foo <- reactive({ ... })
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(foo()$x, foo()$y)
})
```

Comment: Thanks Joe....I found my errors and based on your pointer I am now able to accomplish what I wanted. Thanks a bunch.